# Unable to Find Custom Styles

Tags: android, android-layout

Using styles in my application, I'm unable to get custom styles apart from a custom ActionBar style.

```
<TextView
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="@style/ButtonText"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/button_text"/>
```

normally, Android Studio auto-completes @style references; however, this is not the case. I am  use three values-vXX directories: values, values-v11, and values-v16. Within each, I have a styles.xml file. Each styles.xml contains the following code:

```
<style name="ButtonText" parent="@AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

with the exception of v16, which has an extra line.

Unfortunately, Android Studio doesn't recognize these. The project compiles fine, the apk is built and pushed to the device, but on load, the app crashes -  `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86: Error inflating class <unknown>`

It's referring to the android:textStyle line.

I'm running a project compiled for v14 on a Moto X running 4.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line:

```
android:textStyle="@style/ButtonText"
```

to use the `style` attribute

```
style="@style/ButtonText"
```

`textStyle` is used to set bold, italic and normal, not the style from the definition of styles.

Comment: yeah I'm really embarrassed I just figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Szymon for answering this.

`android:textStyle` is used for bold, italic, and normal styling. The `style` attribute is used to apply custom styles to your view.